# why do I get an error with virtual property in symfony?

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine, api-platform.com

I have this entity

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use ApiPlatform\Metadata\ApiResource;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Criteria;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Annotation\Groups;

#[ApiResource(
    normalizationContext: ["groups" => ["contact", "contact_read"]],
    denormalizationContext: ["groups" => ["contact", "contact_write"]]
)]
#[ORM\Entity]
class Contact
{
    // ...

    #[ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity: Email::class, mappedBy: "contact")]
    #[Groups(["contact"])]
    private $emails;
    
    // ...

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->emails = new ArrayCollection();
    }   

    // ...
    
    public function getEmails()
    {
        return $this->emails;
    }
    
    // ...
}
```

And I want to add a virtual property

```
#[Groups(["contact"])]
public function getPrimaryEmail()
{
    $criteria = Criteria::create()->where(Criteria::expr()->eq("is_primary", true));

    $matches = $this->emails->matching($criteria);

    return ($matches->count()) ? $matches->first()->getAccount() : null;
}
```

and it works....but it doesn't if the name of the method is `getEmail()`

```
#[Groups(["contact"])]
public function getEmail()
{
    $criteria = Criteria::create()->where(Criteria::expr()->eq("is_primary", true));

    $matches = $this->emails->matching($criteria);

    return ($matches->count()) ? $matches->first()->getAccount() : null;
}
```

in that case I get this error

> Unexpected non-iterable value for to-many relation

why is that? Is there a way to leave the method as `getEmail()`?

I'm using API Platform 3.2.10 with symfony 6.4.1

Complete error:

```
{
  "@id": "/errors/400",
  "@type": "hydra:Error",
  "title": "An error occurred",
  "detail": "Unexpected non-iterable value for to-many relation.",
  "status": 400,
  "type": "/errors/400",
  "trace": [
    {
      "file": "vendor/symfony/serializer/Normalizer/AbstractObjectNormalizer.php",
      "line": 192,
      "function": "getAttributeValue",
      "class": "ApiPlatform\\Serializer\\AbstractItemNormalizer",
      "type": "->"
    },
    {
      "file": "vendor/api-platform/core/src/Serializer/AbstractItemNormalizer.php",
      "line": 171,
      "function": "normalize",
      "class": "Symfony\\Component\\Serializer\\Normalizer\\AbstractObjectNormalizer",
      "type": "->"
    },
    {
      "file": "vendor/api-platform/core/src/JsonLd/Serializer/ItemNormalizer.php",
      "line": 111,
      "function": "normalize",
      "class": "ApiPlatform\\Serializer\\AbstractItemNormalizer",
      "type": "->"
    },
    {
      "file": "vendor/symfony/serializer/Debug/TraceableNormalizer.php",
      "line": 58,
      "function": "normalize",
      "class": "ApiPlatform\\JsonLd\\Serializer\\ItemNormalizer",
      "type": "->"
    },
    {
      "file": "vendor/symfony/serializer/Serializer.php",
      "line": 159,
      "function": "normalize",
      "class": "Symfony\\Component\\Serializer\\Debug\\TraceableNormalizer",
      "type": "->"
    },
    {
      "file": "vendor/api-platform/core/src/Hydra/Serializer/CollectionNormalizer.php",
      "line": 91,
      "function": "normalize",
      "class": "Symfony\\Component\\Serializer\\Serializer",
      "type": "->"
    },
    {
      "file": "vendor/api-platform/core/src/Serializer/AbstractCollectionNormalizer.php",
      "line": 106,
      "function": "getItemsData",
      "class": "ApiPlatform\\Hydra\\Serializer\\CollectionNormalizer",
      "type": "->"
    },
    {
      "file": "vendor/api-platform/core/src/Hydra/Serializer/PartialCollectionViewNormalizer.php",
      "line": 50,
      "function": "normalize",
      "class": "ApiPlatform\\Serializer\\AbstractCollectionNormalizer",
      "type": "->"
    },
    {
      "file": "vendor/api-platform/core/src/Hydra/Serializer/CollectionFiltersNormalizer.php",
      "line": 91,
      "function": "normalize",
      "class": "ApiPlatform\\Hydra\\Serializer\\PartialCollectionViewNormalizer",
      "type": "->"
    },
    {
      "file": "vendor/symfony/serializer/Debug/TraceableNormalizer.php",
      "line": 58,
      "function": "normalize",
      "class": "ApiPlatform\\Hydra\\Serializer\\CollectionFiltersNormalizer",
      "type": "->"
    },
    {
      "file": "vendor/symfony/serializer/Serializer.php",
      "line": 159,
      "function": "normalize",
      "class": "Symfony\\Component\\Serializer\\Debug\\TraceableNormalizer",
      "type": "->"
    },
    {
      "file": "vendor/symfony/serializer/Serializer.php",
      "line": 138,
      "function": "normalize",
      "class": "Symfony\\Component\\Serializer\\Serializer",
      "type": "->"
    },
    {
      "file": "vendor/symfony/serializer/Debug/TraceableSerializer.php",
      "line": 47,
      "function": "serialize",
      "class": "Symfony\\Component\\Serializer\\Serializer",
      "type": "->"
    },
    {
      "file": "vendor/api-platform/core/src/State/Processor/SerializeProcessor.php",
      "line": 65,
      "function": "serialize",
      "class": "Symfony\\Component\\Serializer\\Debug\\TraceableSerializer",
      "type": "->"
    },
    {
      "file": "vendor/api-platform/core/src/State/Processor/WriteProcessor.php",
      "line": 42,
      "function": "process",
      "class": "ApiPlatform\\State\\Processor\\SerializeProcessor",
      "type": "->"
    },
    {
      "file": "vendor/api-platform/core/src/Symfony/Controller/MainController.php",
      "line": 111,
      "function": "process",
      "class": "ApiPlatform\\State\\Processor\\WriteProcessor",
      "type": "->"
    },
    {
      "file": "vendor/symfony/http-kernel/HttpKernel.php",
      "line": 181,
      "function": "__invoke",
      "class": "ApiPlatform\\Symfony\\Controller\\MainController",
      "type": "->"
    },
    {
      "file": "vendor/symfony/http-kernel/HttpKernel.php",
      "line": 76,
      "function": "handleRaw",
      "class": "Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\HttpKernel",
      "type": "->"
    },
    {
      "file": "vendor/symfony/http-kernel/Kernel.php",
      "line": 197,
      "function": "handle",
      "class": "Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\HttpKernel",
      "type": "->"
    },
    {
      "file": "vendor/symfony/runtime/Runner/Symfony/HttpKernelRunner.php",
      "line": 35,
      "function": "handle",
      "class": "Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\Kernel",
      "type": "->"
    },
    {
      "file": "vendor/autoload_runtime.php",
      "line": 29,
      "function": "run",
      "class": "Symfony\\Component\\Runtime\\Runner\\Symfony\\HttpKernelRunner",
      "type": "->"
    },
    {
      "file": "public/index.php",
      "line": 5,
      "function": "require_once"
    }
  ],
  "hydra:title": "An error occurred",
  "hydra:description": "Unexpected non-iterable value for to-many relation."
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is probably because symfony serializer determines getEmail as the accessor for the emails property during normalization, which results in the type mismatch, because getEmail returns an single object and emails is a collection.

To avoid these "late" errors, you can improve your code by adding strict types to each property, method parameter and return.

It may still fail, but give you error messages that are easier to understand. If you are lucky, symfony serializer now understands, that getEmail can not be the accessor for $emails because it can see that it will return a different type.

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use ApiPlatform\Metadata\ApiResource;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Criteria;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Annotation\Groups;

#[ApiResource(
    normalizationContext: ["groups" => ["contact", "contact_read"]],
    denormalizationContext: ["groups" => ["contact", "contact_write"]]
)]
#[ORM\Entity]
class Contact
{
    // ...

    /**
     * @var Collection|Email[]
     */
    #[ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity: Email::class, mappedBy: "contact")]
    #[Groups(["contact"])]
    private Collection $emails;
    
    // ...

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->emails = new ArrayCollection();
    }   

    // ...
    
    /**
     * @return Collection|Email[]
     */
    public function getEmails(): Collection
    {
        return $this->emails;
    }
    
    // ...

    #[Groups(["contact"])]
    public function getEmail(): ?Email 
    {
        $criteria = Criteria::create()->where(Criteria::expr()->eq("is_primary", true));

        $matches = $this->emails->matching($criteria);

        return ($matches->count()) ? $matches->first() : null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Same error, Unexpected non-iterable value for to-many relation

Comment: did you step-debug to verify that property-accessor is using getEmail as accessor for $emails?

Comment: Can I look into that using the symfony profiler?

Comment: the symfony profiler cant do that. a good option is the xdebug php extension.